# cordova admob pro plugin by floatinghotpot only showing test banners, not real ads

Tags: cordova, admob

I replaced the admobid from the working example code (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/test/index.html) with my own admobid, but I get only Test Banners. My app is already on the Android Play Store, but there is still just Test Banners on every device I install it on. What is going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by commenting out this line in the code:

isTesting:true